# How to stop CKEditor auto format HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a CMS system using CKEditor and Dust javascript template, user will enter Dust template in ckeditor, and save to database, template will be something like

```
{#News}
   <li><a herf="{Link}">{Title}</a></li>
{/News}
```

When user enter those code in source mode, and switch to rich mode, ckeditor will reformat the code, when they switch back to source mode, code will not be the same code.

I google for solution for days, but not able to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this. My solution was to set  `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;` in config.js.